# Efficient way to select ancestors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="image">
  <div class="placeholder">
    <a class="load iframe" href="https://contestapp.com/images/4"><img src="/uploads/image/image_file/4/thumb_he_sport_nutrition_for_active_kids_photo.jpg?1307271623" alt="Thumb_he_sport_nutrition_for_active_kids_photo"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="user">By </div>
  <div class="actions">
      <span>
        <a class="vote-link" href="/images/4/vote"></a>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a link of class vote-link and I want to select both the the link a.load and the a.load img, How can I do it efficiently via jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you'll need to go up to a common ancestor with [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest).

```
$(this).closest('div.image');
```

Then you'll need to find the link and the image using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find), the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector) and the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector):

```
$(this).closest('div.image').find('a.load, a.load img');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $(this).closest('div.placeholder').find('a.load>img');
var a = $(img).parent();
```

...would be my prefered method, since this would target the img directly, and once you have that as an object, getting its parent anchor should be fairly trivial, in terms of processing.

EDITED: Because I'm an eejit!

Comment: You need start from the anchor though. Since that's where the event comes in

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery Ancestry plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ancestry

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.vote-link').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('div').prevAll('div.placeholder:first').find('a.load, a.load img');
});
```

You go up out one level, then you move up in direction and then you go inward

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/K5tB4/7/

just built this comparing how quickly the three selector/solutions here perform over 256 seperate copies of the structure you hae in place, and it looks to me like JohnP clinches it... just...

Comment: That's an invalid comparison -- the use of `:first` selects only one element. [See valid comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/K5tB4/12/).

Comment: All I did was slap in the selectors that were proposed @lonesomeday. Can't quite get my head around why JohnP's differs so greatly between the two versions to be honest. might be a mental block at my end. could you explain briefly what the hell I'm missing...

Comment: The code you've put in for you and me finds all the `a` and `img` elements; JohnP's only finds the first of each. The `:first` selector reduces the selection to one element.

Answer (score 0):

ummm.... I realise this has now been decided, but...

```
$(this).closest('div.placeholder').find('a.load, a.load>img');
```

...is actually around twice as fast in the comparative 256 element test myself and lonesomeday have linked to within this page.

Just saying is all, since the original question relates to efficiency...?